# Is replication from SQL Server 2008 to PostgreSql possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.2

Is it possible ? Sql Server as publisher(master) and PostgreSql as slave(subscriber) ? Any type of replication really.

Comment: Could you please add more detail about what you're trying to accomplish with the replication setup?

Comment: I see much pgODBC and `OPENROWSET` in your future.

Comment: @swasheck You sound a bit like (an) ORACLE...

Comment: any ideas if you can do it the other way round,  PostGres (Master) to SQL server express (slave)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only ORACLE and IBM-DB2 are officially supported as subscribers. Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151864%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151835%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) for more details.

Also, from sql server 2012, this is being depreciated as well.

*Heterogeneous replication to non-SQL Server subscribers is deprecated. Oracle Publishing is deprecated. **To move data, create solutions using change data capture and SSIS**.
 **[Caution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151864%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) :**
This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.*

Below is a blog post that I found that might be useful to you:  [**Replicating from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL**](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/103-Replicating-from-MS-SQL-Server-to-PostgreSQL.html)

Comment: So answer is no.